# Facebook App: any way to run the app without SSL?

Tags: facebook, ssl, facebook-apps

I am working on my first app for Facebook and facing (probably) with the SSL problem. If I am testing the app, so it's working well. But then I wanted to test the app by my friend - so I assigned him the role "Tester", he accepted it and I sent him the link to the app.

If he opened the app, he got the error **The website is not available - Error 501 (net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE): Unknown error**

I started google it and it looks that the cause is the missing SSL certificate on my hosting, where the app is stored.

**BUT** - how is possible, that the app is working me well without the SSL and to my friend doesn't? If the SSL is required for Facebook apps, why I didn't get the same error?
(I set **Secure Canvas URL:** to **https://example.com/fb-app-directory/**, however I don't have at this domain and hosting any SSL certificate).

I never used before SSL. I bought the domain name on Namecheap and hosting on Hostgator. So now, I should buy a SSL certificate from the offer (http://www.namecheap.com/ssl-certificates.aspx) of Namecheap, right?

Would be suitable for the Facebook app the cheapest one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should buy an SSL cert in order for everyone to be able to access your app. Your friend probably has his settings set so that he browses Facebook securely, in this case he is hitting https://example.com/fb-app-directory/, not your actual URL.

The cheapest one isn't the best one, but it should work as long as it's valid. I would suggest using Heroku though, as that way you get everything you need - for free :)

Comment: Claudiu thank you for the answer. Also, I found http://support.hostgator.com/articles/ssl-certificates/ssl-setup-use/how-to-make-your-facebook-app-ssl-secure -- free shared SSL. What about this? My app is written in PHP and hosted in Hostgator hosting, and I think Heroku is dedicated for RoR apps.

Comment: Also, `The cheapest one isn't the best one, but it should work as long as it's valid.` -- what did you mean? I just thought, that I purchase an SSL certificate and that's it.

Comment: It will work as long as you have a valid SSL cert. However, some certs are more secure from some vendors (which are usually more expensive). You can host on Heroku for you PHP app and you even have a link to create an app on Heroku straight into your app settings in the Facebook dashboard.

Comment: which means as long as I will pay it? Anyway, could you recommend me an SSL certificate with good ratio price/power for Facebook app? Obviously, the lower price, the better.

Comment: Then just buy the cheapest one.

Comment: I found out that shared SSL on Hostgator works fine if you access it directly - but Facebook doesn't allow it when entering your app details (secure canvas URL or secure page tab URL) so you have to get a private SSL for your domain

Comment: @LeeGee, this was posted one year ago. An alternative solution that is still free is appfog.com (service similar to Heroku)

Answer (score 3):

Look, this SSL problem can only be solved by purchasing a valid SSL certificate or looking for a server which can host your app and is SSL certified such as:

- **phpfog.com** - Provides you with some limited space and database service.
- **heroku.com** - Does not provide any storage space for saving dynamically generated data. To have that service, you have to buy the Amazon buckets service which, again, is a costly affair.

If you don't want to invest any money, I would recommend that you go with phpfog - it is easy and its documentation is pretty good.

Comment: phpfog (or appfog) doesn't seem to have SSL on free plan

Comment: @GaborMagyar, they do have.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [proxy](https://github.com/manuks/proxy) in heroku.com and bring your page in secure domain as https://yourapplication.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 0):

"Starting October 1, 2011 Facebook will require a valid SSL Certificate for all pages and applications hosted outside of Facebook."

http://www.wpcode.net/fb-ssl.html/

Maybe you are visiting your application with `http://apps.facebook.com/...` and your friend is visiting with `https://apps.facebook.com/...`.

Another possibility is that your friend has checked "Browse Facebook on a secure connection (https) whenever possible" under "Account Security".

Answer (score -3):

Try [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). It exposes a local web server with just one command:

```
ngrok 80
```

After this you can access your localhost like this: xxxxxxxx.ngrok.com

Comment: Please read question first, it is not asking for localhost server.