# Is there a way to add a page to facebook tab without ssl?

Tags: facebook, iframe, ssl

I am using https://apps.facebook.com/static_html_plus/ to add an iframe but I am getting following error message:

```
Insecure urls found

You should change the following urls to begin with https:// instead of http://, or some browsers will not propery display your content:

http://www.clientwebsite.moon
```

I was contemplating adding a page with just iframe on a free website that allows https but realised it will not show the content unless it is unblocked by users.

Is there a workaround for this situation so that I do not have to buy ssl certificate?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook App: any way to run the app without SSL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12248698/facebook-app-any-way-to-run-the-app-without-ssl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowadays facebook forces us to use SSL in our page tab applications.
You need to buy SSL sertificate. There are cheap ones - about 20$/ year.